# How to access functions from another python file in a sub folder?

Tags: python-3.x, path

my folder structure is,

```
├── handler
│   ├── s3_handler.py
│   
└── service
    ├── service.py
```

s3_handler file contains many functions which i need to use in service.py

I was trying

```
from handlers.s3_handler import *
```

but there is an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "field_mapping_util.py", line 3, in <module>
  from handlers.s3_handler import * 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'handlers'
```

how to resolve this

Comment: your folder structure shows `handler` instead of `handlers`. Is this a typo on your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out.
inside service.py insert,

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from handler.s3_handler import *
```